# Access Denied error thrown while trying to run an SSIS job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to run an SSIS Package using sql script. While I try to run this, I am getting the following error message,

> "Message Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R)
>   SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5000.0 for 64-bit 
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   6:05:54 PM  Could not load package "\MSDB\TestPac" because of error
>   0xC00160AE.  Description: Connecting to the Integration Services
>   service on the computer "Server Name" failed with the following error:
>   "Access is denied."    By default, only administrators have access to
>   the Integration Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the
>   process must be running with administrative privileges in order to
>   connect to the Integration Services service. See the help topic for
>   information on how to configure access to the service.  Source:
>   Started:  6:05:54 PM  Finished: 6:05:54 PM  Elapsed:  0.047 seconds. 
>   The package could not be loaded.  The step failed."

Comment: Please include your SQL script that executes the package. You need to give permissions to the integration services to the user who is executing the script. By default only Admin has rights (as stated in the message).

Comment: It's kind of obvious what the problem is but it's impossible to know the cause without seeing your code. Please provide the code that executes the package

Comment: I am not using any script, am trying to exec this SSIS package from a job.

Comment: Also the user is having admin privilage.

Comment: Clearly the user that is executing the package does NOT have admin privilege.